# Devtools not working and giving strange error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm trying to use Devtools but I'm getting the following error printed to the console:

> DevTools debugger is disabled because it is attached to a process that hosts multiple top-level frames, where DevTools debugger doesn't work properly. Please relaunch the browser with --disable-features=ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold to enable debugger.

I'm on Chrome Beta 115.0.5790.56 and this only started happening recently. Is this a bug in Chrome?

Comment: It sounds like a design change, does the switch they say to use fix it?  Also, beta so use at your own risk and not reflective of production releases..  And - https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-reviews/c/2-ANsUBntL4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://niek.github.io/chrome-features/ :

> ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold
>
> Reuses RenderProcessHost up to a certain threshold. This mode ignores
> the soft process limit and behaves just like a process-per-site policy
> for all sites, with an additional restriction that a process may only
> be reused while the number of main frames in that process stays below
> a threshold.

The feature is currently disabled by default in the normal chrome release but appears to have been set to enabled by default in the Chrome Beta branch.

I'm using Chrome beta version 116.0.5845.42 which has a toggle for this feature in `chrome://flags/#enable-process-per-site-up-to-main-frame-threshold`.

The description there is

> Enable ProcessPerSite up to main frame threshold
> Proactively reuses same-site renderer processes to host multiple main frames, up to a certain threshold. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Android, Fuchsia, Lacros

Disabling the feature and restarting the browser will get rid of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not require downloading Beta branch.

I have been debugging with Chrome Version 115.0.5790.110 (latest) every day and first started seeing this issue yesterday or the day before.

This version does not support changing the settings via chrome://flags.

Instead open the Windows command line by typing "cmd" in the start menu and run:

```
start chrome  --disable-features=ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold
```

Note that even without running chrome like this, I noticed that after restarting the browser a few times, eventually I was able to debug as normal.

Comment: The command just does the same thing as disabling the feature via chrome://flags but via the command line instead. Only difference is that if you open chrome any other way the changes won't persist.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Version 115.0.5790.114 (Official Build) (x86_64) on MacOS and see the same message in the console.

If I look for the flag in:

chrome://flags/#enable-process-per-site-up-to-main-frame-threshold

It isn't there.

I can get rid of the error though by starting Chrome from the Terminal with:

$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-features=ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold

Hopefully Google fixes this chop chop.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold, started mid-July. I have a JavaScript app with several embedded iFrames. Debugger complained too many iframes and my source JavaScript files were not loaded into the debugger. All works in Firefox and Chrome

Updated chrome now to 115.0.5790.171

Error went away, but still, no source JavaScript in my debugger. Other sites work, just not my app.

I tried:

start chrome  --disable-features=ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold

Still no source code in debugger.

Do not see flags in chrome://flags

[[image: flags missing][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmkvm.jpg)
[image: no source files]
[image: version info]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Now fixed in 116.0.5854.97

Answer (score 0):

I am running Version 115.0.5790.114 (Official Build) (x86_64) on Ubuntu 20.04, I didnt found the flags on chrome://flags instead I tryied to run chrome through command line:

```
google-chrome  --disable-features=ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold
```

It works very well, in a few days chrome started to works normals as usual

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> on your keyboard – or the *refresh* icon in your web browser.